# Добрый день, проблема в том что через форму обратной связи часть сообщений приходит пустая :(

Tags: php, форма

ребята. Уже пол дня убил, но не могу понять, "то ли лыжи не едут то ли я", в общем, есть форма обратной связи на сайте, запустили рекламу. За пол дня 6 клиентов оставили заявку на звонок, и только 2 прислали данные, остальные 5 пришли просто пусытые (тег 'required")

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['namee'];
$phone = $_POST['phonee'];
$to = "support@watchx.top";
$subject = "Phone number";
mail ($to, $subject, $name . ' ' . $phone);
?>
```

Форма в HTML

```
<form action="mailer.php" class="form__inputs" method="post" 
name="order_form" target="_blank">

<input type="text" name="namee" placeholder="Введите Ваше ФИО" 
class="form__input" value="" />

<input type="text" name="phonee" placeholder="Введите Ваш Телефон" 
class="form__input"  value="" required="required"  placeholder="" />
```

Читал что якобы Сафари не поддерживает тег Required, но попробывал с айфона и сафари отправить пустую заявку - не дало. Со всех тестовых браузеров все отлично приходит.

Comment: Остальные 4*, опечатался

Comment: зачем пологатся на required ? перед отправкой формы, проверяйте все необходимые поля

Comment: Тут проблема не в том что "Спамят", а я хотел узнать, вдруг они пишут сообщения, но они не доходят. То есть это исключено? Просто кликают на кнопку?

Comment: @CompexStar в целом можно сказать что да, исключено. Скорее это боты тыкают.

Answer (score 1):

Ну обрабатывайте на уровне пыхи:

```
$name = trim($_POST['namee']);
$phone = trim($_POST['phonee']);
if (!empty($phone) AND !empty($name))
{
    $to = "support@watchx.top";
    $subject = "Phone number";
    mail ($to, $subject, $name . ' ' . $phone);
}
```